# I am trying to remove email with ';' value from column which has multiple emails

Tags: sql, oracle

If I use `replace(email, ';', '')` it will remove all the ';' from the value which has list of emails. My requirement is it will need to remove only the paticular email along with ';' if it is at end or at the begining for that particular email. 
EG:

```
abc@yahoo.com;efg@yahoo.com;hij@yahoo.com;ab1@yahoo.com
```

If I want to remove abc@yahoo.com; then the result should be

```
efg@yahoo.com;hij@yahoo.com;ab1@yahoo.com
```

or if I want to remove hij@yahoo.com; then the result should be

```
abc@yahoo.com;efg@yahoo.com;ab1@yahoo.com
```

Query :

```
DECLARE 

  v_sql    VARCHAR2(5000); 
  v_email VARCHAR2(5000):= 'abc@yahoo.com';

  v_sql:=UPDATE L05460176.SI_Recipient set email = case when (:1||';') then replace (lower (replace (email, :1||';' )), chr(32),'')  
                            when (';'||:1) then email =  replace (lower (replace (email, ';'||:1 )), 
chr(32),'') WHERE EVENT = 'XYZ'

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql 
  USING v_email ;
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single column!

Comment: Why does you pseudo-code imply dynamic SQL? There's no need for it here. The problem is convoluted enough without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hello @GanesanVC I am sure that you will find one of this answer very useful. It would be nice to get feedback from you - to mark the correct answer... Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `trim()` and `replace()`:

```
trim(both ';' from
     replace(';' || emails || ';', ';' || 'hij@yahoo.com' || ';', ';')
    )
```

That said, I would recommend a different data model.  Oracle has many alternative solutions for storing lists of things -- from a traditional junction/association table to JSON to nested tables.

Comment: The replaced value should be `';'` and not `''` (which in Oracle is the same as `NULL`); otherwise if you replace an e-mail in the middle of the string it will remove both delimiters and concatenate the preceding with the succeeding e-mails and you need to put one separator back to keep them separated.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use replace + replace:

```
select 
replace(replace('efg@yahoo.com;hij@yahoo.com;ab1@yahoo.com', 'hij@yahoo.com', ''), ';;', ';') 
from dual;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4fc34e0ac2a72223a5a221685952f3a9)